# [Pyomo]How to generate a constraints via a loop

Tags: pyomo

all

i want to create a set of constraints, as following:

Pg[0] <= Pmax[0]

Pg[1] <= Pmax[1]

Pg[3] <= Pmax[3]

Pg[4] <= Pmax[4]

Pg[5] <= Pmax[5]

and, my code is as following:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
Ngen = 5
Pmax = [40, 170, 520, 200, 100]
model.Ngen = pyo.Set(dimen=Ngen)
model.Pg = pyo.Var(model.Ngen)

def Co1(model):
    return ((model.Pg[ii] for ii in model.Ngen) <= (Pmax[jj]  for jj in range(Ngen)))

model.Co1 = pyo.Constraint(rule=Co1)
```

but, the Python Console tells me:

" TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'generator' "

HOW DO I RECORRECT this?

and the other quesiton, if the Pmax is not a list, but a numpy-ndarray. somethings will different?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the fact that your constraint is defined over a set. Pyomo allows you to pass `args` to the `Constraint` constructor that define the set(s) of that constraint.

Therefore your final line should look something like:

```py
model.Co1 = pyo.Constraint(model.Ngen, rule=Co1)
```

The second issue is the constraint expression itself. Now that this is defined with respect to a `Set`, you need only express the constraint in terms of a given index (say `i`), because the `rule` also expects arguments pertaining to each index of each `Set` of the `Constraint`:

```py
def Co1(model, i):
    return model.Pg[i] <= Pmax[i]
```

Finally, the `Set` you're defining is of `size=5`, not `dimen=5`. Sets are usually `dimen=1` unless you're working with say arc links of a network in which case they would be of dimension 2. Since your set is defined over integers, the easiest way to add this is via `RangeSet` which defines all the integers from 1 to N:

```py
model.Ngen = pyo.RangeSet(Ngen)
```

Given this, the only thing to change is that the list `Pmax` is 0-indexed and so our constraint will need to account for `i` being offset by one:

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
Ngen = 5
Pmax = [40, 170, 520, 200, 100]
model.Ngen = pyo.RangeSet(Ngen)
model.Pg = pyo.Var(model.Ngen)

def Co1(model, i):
    return model.Pg[i] <= Pmax[i - 1]

model.Co1 = pyo.Constraint(model.Ngen, rule = Co1)

model.pprint()

# 1 RangeSet Declarations
#     Ngen : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=5, Domain=Integers, Ordered=True, Bounds=(1, 5)
#         Virtual
# 
# 1 Var Declarations
#     Pg : Size=5, Index=Ngen
#         Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
#           1 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
#           2 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
#           3 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
#           4 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
#           5 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
# 
# 1 Constraint Declarations
#     Co1 : Size=5, Index=Ngen, Active=True
#         Key : Lower : Body  : Upper : Active
#           1 :  -Inf : Pg[1] :  40.0 :   True
#           2 :  -Inf : Pg[2] : 170.0 :   True
#           3 :  -Inf : Pg[3] : 520.0 :   True
#           4 :  -Inf : Pg[4] : 200.0 :   True
#           5 :  -Inf : Pg[5] : 100.0 :   True
# 
# 3 Declarations: Ngen Pg Co1
```

NumPy arrays can be sliced in exactly the same way as lists so the above constraint will still work fine if you change `Pmax = np.array([40, 170, 520, 200, 100])`